# cursor won't move when using move() or wmove() when using the curses library

Tags: c++, unix, cursor, curses

I have this program which prints the first 5 lines or more of a text file to a curses window and then prints some personalized input. but after printing the lines from the text file, the cursor wont' move when using move or wmove. I printed a word after using both and refresh()  but it is printed in the last position the cursor was in. I tried mvprintw and mvwprintw but that way I got no output at all.
this is a part of the code

```
while (! feof(results_file))
    {
        fgets(line,2048,results_file);
        printw("%s",line);
    }
fclose(results_file);
mvwprintw(results_scrn,num_rows_res,(num_col_res/2) - 2,"Close");
wrefresh(results_scrn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are trying to print outside the bounds of the window.

In particular, I would guess that here:

```
mvwprintw(results_scrn,num_rows_res,(num_col_res/2) - 2,"Close");
```

...`num_rows_res` is the number of rows in the `results_scrn` window - but that means that the valid row coordinates range from `0` to `num_rows_res - 1`.

If you try to `move()` or `wmove()` outside the window, the cursor will not actually move; a subsequent `printw()` or `wprintw()` will print at the previous cursor position.  If you try to `mvprintw()` or `mvwprintw()`, the whole call will fail at the point of trying to move the cursor, and so it won't print anything at all.

Here's a complete demonstration (just printing to `stdscr` which has `LINES` rows and `COLS` columns):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;

    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();

    /* This succeeds: */
    mvprintw(1, 1, ">>>");

    /* This tries to move outside the window, and fails before printing: */
    mvprintw(LINES, COLS / 2, "doesn't print at all");

    /* This tries to move outside the window, and fails: */
    move(LINES, COLS / 2);

    /* This prints at the cursor (which hasn't successfully moved yet): */
    printw("prints at current cursor");

    /* This is inside the window, and works: */
    mvprintw(LINES - 1, COLS / 2, "prints at bottom of screen");

    refresh();
    ch = getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

(In fact the functions do return a result; if you check it, you'll find that it's `ERR` in the cases that fail.)